# Movies button missing in Purchased items in iTunes

Tags: itunes, movie

I've bought some movies in iTunes on my Mac. Now I want to download them to my Windows XP PC in iTunes. (Both machines have the latest iTunes version installed.)

According to [the description at the apple web site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519?viewlocale=en_US), I should see the movies in the "Purchased" section of the quick links. I can get to the "Purchased" section fine, except that I don't get a "Movies" button at all.

Any ideas about how to get the movies button (or get the movies to the other pc in an other way)?

Comment: Three unrelated questions: Could you show us a screenshot of what you do see? Is the movie already downloaded to your Mac? Are you viewing Purchased on your Mac or PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably in an iTunes-restricted country. While any user may re-download apps and books, re-downloads of music and movies are restricted to [certain countries](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5085).

You'll need to manually copy the movies over to the XP computer. Note that you will need to activate iTunes with your AppleID to be able to play them.

Answer (score -1):

That's because most movies are not yet available to redownload like music and apps are.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about—once you purchase anything through iTunes you can download it at any time free of charge (which the exception of rentals).

Comment: What can't you re-download?

Comment: Some TV shows and movies, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I have not heard of that; unless you can find an example of this I am fairly sure you are in some way misinformed.

Comment: http://hothardware.com/m/News/Apple-iTunes-Movie-ReDownloads-Not-Coming-Anytime-Soon/Default.aspx a quick google finds this, of course this is from a year ago, so maybe things have changed

Comment: It seems to say at press time *no* movies were available for re-download, and as all that I know of *are*, I expect it's completely outdated.

Comment: Ahhh it depends where you live! http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5085

Comment: Oh, that's the confusion! Good sleuthing.